# how to avoid pops up in react native webview .?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a webview and I want to block popups while user is moving from page to page ,by popup I mean Ads that belong to the site that I am calling inside source of webview.
could you please help me on that, this is how I am building my webview :

```
<WebView
      source={webapp}
      ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
      style={webView}
      renderError={this.handleRenderError}
      onError={this.handleRenderError}
      onLoad={this.handleOnLoadEnd}
      renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
      startInLoadingState
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      decelerationRate="fast"
    />
```

I have added some code to prevent these popsup , it didn't wrok

```
  ...
  injectedJavascript={jsCode}

 const  jsCode = 'document.querySelectorAll("iframe").setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation");';
```

Comment: There's not much info to go on here...

Comment: what popups are you referring to? are these popups made in react-native or these belong to web?

Comment: You need to show the source code of the webview and ads you are talking about. You might be able to do something with the [injectedJavascript prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#injectedjavascript)

Comment: I have edited my post